# Average numbers in the format "Minutes:seconds.fractions_of_seconds" in Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, average

I've tried doing a custom format, but don't have any luck. I always get a divide by zero error. Ideally, I'd be able to average "1:00.0, 1:30.00, and 2:00.00" and have the function return "90.0" OR "1:30.0"
Can someone help me convert the times into values that the average function can understand?
This is in Google Sheets

Comment: No they're in 3 separate cells

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `1:00.0` is in A1, `1:30.00` in A2 etc. The mix of `:` and `,` seems not to be accepted as a number format for data entry, so your data is presumably strings. These need first to be converted to numbers. This might be achieved with something like:

```
=ArrayFormula(value("0:"&A1:A100))
```

in B1. It not only assumes you have 100 rows of data but also that your data points do not individually equal or exceed one hour unless expressed as 60 minutes or more.

You may want to format the results with Format – Number, More Formats, Custom number format…:

```
mm:ss.000
```

though in this format hours are not shown.

In that format the result of:

```
=average(B1:B3)
```

should be:

```
01:30.000
```

Might not work in old Google Sheets.